# How can prevent the scroll event execute more times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am implementing a new feature to let my page to support endless scroll AJAX show. But when I pull down my page scroll bar, sometimes the same request occurs.

This means that `alert(nextPage)` method is executed and it shows the same result. I've added the  `event.stopPropagation()` code, but it didn't solve the problem. How can i fix it?

```
(function(window, undefined) {
   var app = {
      event: {
         add: function(obj, type, handle) {
            try {
               obj.addEventListener(type, handle, false);
            } catch (e) {
               try {
                  obj.attachEvent('on' + type, handle);
               } catch (e) {
                  obj['on' + type] = handle;
               }
            }
         }

      },
      scroll: function(id, url) {
         $.get(url, function(html) {
            $("#" + id).append(html)
         });
      }
   }
})(window);
```

HTML

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      app.event.add(window, "scroll", function(event) {
         var nextPage = getNextPage();
         alert(nextPage);
         app.scroll("productTable", '?page=' + nextPage);
         if (event && event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
         } else {
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
         }

      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: hi  @Khalid,  can you help me for this question? thx.

Comment: I suggest you to pass a parameter to the function that sends the ajax request, if the parameter is the same as the old one, in this case no need to send the ajax request, and if it's different, you can send it. I don't really know what this parameter should be, but it should be something that makes you sure that you'll get different results... I can't really help you with your code, I need to leave know for work , so I just tried to give you a hint. Good Luck